QYT KT-8900D programming 70cm
Bought this radio about 5 months ago.
Programmed some channels into memory for 2m Repeaters - works well.
Now have some 70cm repeaters here and try to put them into memory channels.
But for 70cm no shift, not tone  is stored.
For example: 439.225 / 431.625 tone 88.5 with 12.5kHz
In VFO Mode, the 70cm repeater works.
Has anybody had this issue?
I have ordered programming cable - maybe in programm mode I am able to set.
Done a radio reset: Now also 2m repeaters cannot anymore stored into memory.
How do I restore the ability to store 2 m repeater and 40 cm repeater information in my radio?

Hello, and welcome here! I've added a technical question to your question post (that seemed to fit better whether someone else has had the same problem: Knowing that wouldn't have helped you much, I guess). Can you please check that this was OK from your side?
